# How to implement the SQL query in MarkLogic javascript?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I have an `SQL` query that I want to implement in `Javascript` query type in MarkLogic. The goal is to return all the `URIs` of the query result.

**Below is the SQL query I want to convert:**

```
SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT_TABLE
WHERE WADCTO IN ('WM', 'WO')
AND (WASRST NOT IN ('02', 'M', 'M9')) AND (WASTRX = 0)
```

**Here is my current Javascript query that I tested in query console but is not returning the same number of rows like the SQL query:**

```js
cts.uris(null, null, 
  cts.andQuery([
    cts.collectionQuery("JDEdwards"), 
    cts.collectionQuery("WorkOrder_Document"),
    cts.andQuery([
      cts.orQuery([
        cts.elementRangeQuery(fn.QName("http://www.example.com/ads/JDEdwards/document", "WADCTO"),"=","WO"),
        cts.elementRangeQuery(fn.QName("http://www.example.com/ads/JDEdwards/document", "WADCTO"),"=","WM")
      ]),
      cts.andQuery([
        cts.elementRangeQuery(fn.QName("http://www.example.com/ads/JDEdwards/document", "WASRST"),"!=","02"),
        cts.elementRangeQuery(fn.QName("http://www.example.com/ads/JDEdwards/document", "WASRST"),"!=","M"),
        cts.elementRangeQuery(fn.QName("http://www.example.com/ads/JDEdwards/document", "WASRST"),"!=","09")
      ]),
      cts.elementRangeQuery(fn.QName("http://www.example.com/ads/JDEdwards/document", "WASTRX"),"=","0")
    ])
  ])
);
```

Note that I have setup range index for elements `WADCTO`, `WASRST` and `WASTRX`.

**Is there anything missing or wrong with the logic of my code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A range query can specify an OR-related list of values.  Also, the `cts.notQuery()` can negate a query.  Possibly something similar to the following sketch might get closer.

```
cts.uris(null, null, 
  cts.andQuery([
    cts.collectionQuery("JDEdwards"),
    cts.collectionQuery("WorkOrder_Document"),
    cts.elementRangeQuery(fn.QName("...", "WADCTO"),"=", ["WO", "WM"]),
    cts.notQuery(
      cts.elementRangeQuery(fn.QName("...", "WASRST"),"=", ["02", "M", "09"])
      ),
    cts.elementRangeQuery(fn.QName("...", "WASTRX"),"=", "0")
    ]);
```

Things to check include

- whether the target documents are in both collections
- whether the namespaces are correct for the elements
- whether the range indexes have the string data type (WASTRX was a number in the SQL version of the query)

If all else fails, try removing query clauses until the query works to find the problematic query clause.

Hoping that helps,